# Firebase Hosting - A/B testing or progressive rollouts

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

This is a feature I've been wondering about. Really loving Firebase Hosting but wanted to know are there any plans to allow traffic shaping as you can achieve on Google Cloud Platform? For example roll a new version out to 5% of visitors, do 50% A/B testing etc?

If there are that would be great, if not I guess it will be a matter of creating a custom server setup. Thanks

Comment: this belongs to firebase support, not StackOverflow. Let them know at https://firebase.google.com/support